# Anyone have suggestion for ionic 4 datepicker component?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing one business app in ionic 4 which have best UI and i am looking for good component for calendar/datepicker. I don't want to use their native typical component. I would appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be helpful if you really don't want to use typical ionic date-picker https://github.com/logisticinfotech/ionic4-datepicker

actually, I am using it in my current project, it's working like a charm

Comment: i've tried about 5 different date pickers and even a calendar module, and this really is the only solid solution short of importing material just to get one.